# How can I add a scroll on the Zingchart-grid?

Tags: scroll, grid, zingchart

I want to scroll would need to add some code cause the scroll?

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid module included in the ZingChart library is a read-only grid.  It does not include any interactive features like scrolling.

We are working on a much more interactive grid with tons of features. Hopefully that will be available in the next few months.

Comment: Also, I am on the ZingChart team.  If you have any additional questions you are welcome to reach out to support@zingchart.com